# How can I set up Oracle APEX on my computer?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I don't want to use Oracle APEX in a browser. Is there a way to use it as a desktop app without addicting to the browser?

If so, please, send the Download link and the Installation instruction link if it exists.

Comment: "I don't want to use Oracle APEX in a browser" - why, if I may ask? Browser is a *key* here; you - as developer - as well as end users need **only browser** to do everything about Apex. If you don't want it, perhaps you should consider different technology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle APEX is using a web based user interface. There are future plans to expose the development environment as [PWA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_web_app), however this is still not implemented as far as I know.

It is perfectly possible, however, to create a PWA in APEX and install it in your Windows so that it can the look and feel of a native windows application. It will still have the same restrictions as any other web app, including the need of internet connectivity, unless you run your local APEX instance.